# Ember-Pouch not syncing?

Tags: firebase, ember-cli, pouchdb

I like to fix the cross brower sync in https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog. If I swap out the adapter for a Firebase adapter everything works as expected. (See https://github.com/broerse/ember-cli-blog-fire) It can be some CouchDB setup error on my side but there are no errors in the console. Is there some simple thing I keep overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the ember-pouch readme to fix this, but to answer here: what you need to do is add

```
afterModel: function (recordArray) {
    // This tells PouchDB to listen for live changes and
    // notify Ember Data when a change comes in.
    new PouchDB('mydb').changes({
      since: 'now', 
      live: true
    }).on('change', function () {
      recordArray.update();
    });
  }
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Now just move it to the adapter Nolan. I am happy since: 'now' ;-)